# Perform a Ping and nbtstat -a commands with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, ping

Good Day

I'm working as an IT in a company with a very large amount of computers, so it happens to have a lot of DNS issues.

I'm trying to write a batch File to

> 1. Prompt for a hostname
> 2. Ping host
> 3. Perform an nbtstat -a on the IP address that ping returns
> 4. Show both results on screen

So far, i tried this kind of code :

```bat
@echo off
Set /p host= "Hostname: " 
ping %host%>> C:\Ping.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Well, since my batch file competencies are pretty minimal, so far i've made this :

@echo off
Set /p host= "Hostname: "
ping %host%>> C:\Ping.txt

But got problems to figure out how to isolate IP address to put it on a variable and do a nbtstat

Comment: Code does not go into comments well. Please edit your question to reflect additional information provided.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it:

```
@echo off
set /p hostname="> "
ping %hostname%
for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%# in ('ping -n 1 %hostname%') do nbtstat -a %%#&goto a
:a
```

Comment: Just tried it  and it' actually just looping around, prompting for hostname again and again, without showing any results.

Comment: What exactly did you try out? If you've already got the result of ping in a .txt file, you can just use my for-loop on that (replace middle part with `in (C:\Ping.txt)`). Should it not work, check what "%%#" expands to (`do echo %%#`).

Comment: Well, it DOES work after all.. REALLY weird tho. My files was called PING.BAT and I think, for some reasons, that was the issue. I renamed it to something else, and it worked like a charm. Tried to rename it back to ping.bat, and it did the loop thing again without giving any results.
I don't know if there's a logic explanation, but anyway, it's working now..
Thank you very much.

Comment: Because it keeps calling itself instead of actually pinging (as the command for ping is `ping`).

Comment: Mmmm make a lot of sense now you mention it.. I feel like a fool, haha! 
Thanks a lot for your help. Really appreciated.